# How to calculate Accuracy F1-Score Precision Sensitivity etc

Tags: r, precision, data-mining, confusion-matrix

I'm trying to learn R. So I found some practices on internet this is one of them. I want to calculate Accuracy, F1-Score, Precision, Sensitivity etc from this code. But I can't even calculate confusionmatrix.
What should i do? any one help

```
net = neuralnet(formul,data=train_data,hidden=5,linear.output=FALSE)
plot(net)
predict_net_test <- compute(net,test_data[,1:9])
predict_result<-round(predict_net_test$net.result, digits = 0)
net.prediction = c("benign", "malignant")[apply(predict_result, 1, which.max)]
predict.table = table(cleanedData$Class[-index], net.prediction)
predict.table

CrossTable(x = cleanedData$Class[-index], y = net.prediction,
       prop.chisq=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very sure why you are calling the actual labels from another dataframe `cleanedData` and also the packages you are using. Please provide them in the future. You have the confusion matrix, just feed that into caret's `confusionMatrix()` for stats, for example:

```
library(caret)
library(neuralnet)

dat = data.frame(matrix(runif(1000),100))
dat$Class = sample(c("benign", "malignant"),100,replace=TRUE)
dat$Class = factor(dat$Class)

train_data = dat[1:70,]
test_data = dat[71:100,]

net = neuralnet(Class ~ .,data=train_data,hidden=5,linear.output=FALSE)
predict_net_test = c("benign", "malignant")[max.col(predict(net,test_data))]
```

You need to put the prediction first:

```
predict.table = table(predict_net_test,test_data$Class)
```

Then:

```
confusionMatrix(predict.table,positive="malignant")
                
predict_net_test benign malignant
       benign         5         7
       malignant     10         8
                                          
               Accuracy : 0.4333          
                 95% CI : (0.2546, 0.6257)
    No Information Rate : 0.5             
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.8192          
                                          
                  Kappa : -0.1333         
                                          
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 0.6276          
                                          
            Sensitivity : 0.5333          
            Specificity : 0.3333          
         Pos Pred Value : 0.4444          
         Neg Pred Value : 0.4167          
             Prevalence : 0.5000          
         Detection Rate : 0.2667          
   Detection Prevalence : 0.6000          
      Balanced Accuracy : 0.4333          
                                          
       'Positive' Class : malignant
```

For precision recall, do:

```
    confusionMatrix(predict.table,positive="malignant",mode = "prec_recall")

Confusion Matrix and Statistics

                
predict_net_test benign malignant
       benign         3         8
       malignant     10         9
                                         
               Accuracy : 0.4            
                 95% CI : (0.2266, 0.594)
    No Information Rate : 0.5667         
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.9782         
                                         
                  Kappa : -0.2442        
                                         
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 0.8137         
                                         
              Precision : 0.4737         
                 Recall : 0.5294         
                     F1 : 0.5000         
             Prevalence : 0.5667         
         Detection Rate : 0.3000         
   Detection Prevalence : 0.6333         
      Balanced Accuracy : 0.3801         
                                         
       'Positive' Class : malignant
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can calculate confusion matrix  now.  So if I want to calculate precision, recall, f1-score do i have to calculate with my own? Can I do this on R?

Comment: so all i have to do add  "mode = "prec_recall"? impressed. thanks a lot. I think so i have to keep searching functions and libraries for improve in r.